# How to use plotfile in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data with the `plotfile` function of matplotlib, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *

x = arange(0,10,0.001)
y = sin(x)
savetxt("test.dat",column_stack((x,y)))

plotfile("test.dat",(0,))
show()
```

this gives me the following error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.000000000000000021e-03 9.99999833333341681
```

using the `genfromtxt()` function works perfect with the generated data so I don't see
why there should be an error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) uses a single space as the column delimiter.

However, the default delimiter for [`matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plotfile#matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile) is a comma.

One way to fix is to specify a comma as the column-delimiter in your call to `savetxt`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np 
np.savetxt("test.dat", np.column_stack((x, y)), delimiter=',')
```